# Logstash event @timestamp adjustment

Tags: ruby, logstash

i want to calculate "event.start" from "event.end" and "event.duration", so a subtraction of "event.end" and "event.duration"

"event.end": "2019-10-15T07:34:14.000Z",

"event.duration": 30, (sec.)

Thereafter, event.duration is to be converted into nanoseconds, ie multiplication * 1000000000.

I've looked at using the ruby plug in but my ruby knowledge is zero.

My first attempt is this:

```
if !([event.duration] == 0) {
    mutate  {
        add_field => {"event.end" => "%{@timestamp}" }
            }
            ruby {
#                   init => "require 'time'"
#                   code => "
#                           diff = event.get('start_date') - event.get('end_date')
#                           event.set('timediff') = diff;
#                           "
                        code => "event.set('event.duration', event.get('event.duration').to_i * 1000000000))"   
            }
        }
```

But get the following error message:

```
[2019-10-15T12:11:05,640][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SyntaxError) (ruby filter code):2: syntax error, unexpected ')'
 event.set('event.duration', event.get('event.duration').to_i * 1000000000)) 
                                                                           ^
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> event.set('event.duration', event.get('event.duration').to_i * 1000000000))

You have 2 opening `(` and 3 closing `)`, which leads to the `unexpected ')'` error. Just remove the final closing parenthesis that the compiler indicated with a `^`.

Comment: @user2931829 If this answer solved you problem, [Accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you have another question, open a new question instead of posting additional questions in the answers section.